# How to create corner box with content in android?

Tags: android

How can I create a table with a round border, similar to the following image, in Android?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just take a look at the [official Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) for making shapes via XML.

You could create a box.xml file that defines your rectangle as described in the examples provided:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
        android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="45"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```